# Automating a data feed into a PostgreSQL table when the number of columns could change and there are duplicate names

Tags: postgresql

My company uses a third-party vendor to get all of our [NPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_Promoter) information.  I'm trying to set up a data feed from this vendor into our data warehouse, which runs PostgreSQL.

The feed is in the form of 2 tab-separated text files: "question mapping" and the responses.  The question map is one row per question, with columns for question id, question text, question label question type, etc - straightforward.  The responses are one row per survey response, with a column for each question and stuff like user id, etc.  Here are the 2 biggest problems:

1. The survey questions sometimes use the same question ID for different questions, resulting in multiple columns in the response data having the same name but not being the same question.
2. The number of questions could change, resulting in a different number of columns in the data.

Both of these things make it a real headache to automate a data feed into a single table.

I'm afraid I don't quite know how to phrase my real question other than, "Does anyone have any ideas how I can accomplish this?"  If I think of something better than that, I'll come and update this, so for now:

**Does anyone have any ideas at all about how I can efficiently set up my automated data feed without having to always drop and recreate everything?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is a mess and doesn't really have well defined columns you can use the [entity attribute value pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), where you turn each fact into a set of rows with 4 columns - a unique row id, the same entity id for each row extracted from the map, an attribute column (where you put what would be the name of the column) you get from the key of the map, and a value column where you put the value from the map. It's not that neat but you can still query it and you won't have to drop it when you receive a map with a new column.

Comment: I had considered and dismissed that idea due to space concerns initially, but I think it's really the only way to make automating easy and efficient.  It will introduce new complications of how to compare a user's answers to, say, 2 different questions, but I think that's an alright trade-off for actually being able to get the data into our data warehouse and making it queryable.  Thanks very much!

Comment: I guess once you have it persisted in that (not too queryable) format you can always replicate and cast the data into various columnar formats for easier analytics later or on a recurring basis, as in define and populate new tables with columns mapped from attributes in your EAV store.